# Website Architecture

Tags: c#, asp.net, architecture

I was thinking of a web project whose architecture would be something like this,

Website would have two layer

**Data Access layer**

It would be a project containing webservices & will work like a mediator between presentation layer and database.

**Presentation layer**

It will be a simple website build from HTML, JavaScript and CSS only, and will communicate with data access layer to get and/or post data to and from the database.

Now Question : Is that possible to create an Asp.net session like functionality in my presentation layer using just HTML, JavaScript, Cookies came into my mind first of all but it's not much secured do any one has more relevant, secure & logical solution for this one ?

Thanx in advance.

Comment: I'm confused.  You have this tagged as C# and asp.net, but you're planning on building a site using plain HTML pages?  Can you clarify?

Comment: That whole project contains Data access layer too that would be developed using C# and asp.net.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter if you use HTML or dynamic pages. Depending of what server side environment you use, every first time that the client requests the page, the session is created. This means that even if you are using AJAX to update page content, anyway AJAX will request the server and will have the ability to use Session object on server. In ASP.NET WebServices (That AJAX will call them) you may configure WebMethod to allow or to not allow of using Session.

Comment: Do you mean if a website would have just HTML pages in it and doesn't use .net framework at all and a request for a page from that website is generated it will create a session ??? I thought sessions are generated in asp.net environment only.

Comment: Asp.Net renders pages to HTML, so the browser doesn't see static HTML and a dynamic page (WebForms/MVC) any differently.  Session state is a server-side function, so if you're using ASP.net Web Services for your web service, it's available just like it would be if you were using WebForms/MVC.

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you mean might be REST and Ajax 's functions. Presentation layer is the view, data access layer is the controller, the model is where the database will accessed, and controller will call the function defined in the model